# How to fetch data from array and insert to database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hello i Have a problem related to array,i am trying to request graph api and saves data in database.here is my array

```
Array
(
[threadId] => t_mid.1445648572476:316f06a4adc6d7dd57
[sender] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => rajesh Prasad Shah
                        [email] => 543634645764577@facebook.com
                        [id] => 543634645764577
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => rjtest
                        [email] => 849929567895403@facebook.com
                        [id] => 849929567895403
                    )

            )

    )

[messages] => Array
    (
        [messages] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [message] => Same to u dear.
                        [from] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => rajesh Prasad Shah
                                [email] => 543634645764577@facebook.com
                                [id] => 543634645764577
                            )

                        [created_time] => 2015-12-31T11:31:24+0000
                        [id] => m_mid.1451561484487:5b3276ddd9d86d1480
                        [to] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => rjtest
                                                [email] => 849929567895403@facebook.com
                                                [id] => 849929567895403
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [tags] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => inbox
                                            )

                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => source:chat
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [message] => Happy New Year to all of you
                        [from] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => rjtest
                                [email] => 849929567895403@facebook.com
                                [id] => 849929567895403
                            )

                        [created_time] => 2015-12-31T10:37:47+0000
                        [id] => m_mid.1451558267514:4c017e5a1f8e997586
                        [to] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => rajesh Prasad Shah
                                                [email] => 543634645764577@facebook.com
                                                [id] => 543634645764577
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [tags] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => inbox
                                            )

                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => read
                                            )

                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => sent
                                            )

                                        [3] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => source:web
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [message] => Happy New Year to all of you
                        [from] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => rjtest
                                [email] => 849929567895403@facebook.com
                                [id] => 849929567895403
                            )

                        [created_time] => 2015-12-31T09:44:49+0000
                        [id] => m_mid.1451555089630:1036078c7bcabeed78
                        [to] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => rajesh Prasad Shah
                                                [email] => 543634645764577@facebook.com
                                                [id] => 543634645764577
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [tags] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => inbox
                                            )

                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => read
                                            )

                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => sent
                                            )

                                        [3] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => source:web
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [message] => Happy New Year to all of you
                        [from] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => rjtest
                                [email] => 849929567895403@facebook.com
                                [id] => 849929567895403
                            )

                        [created_time] => 2015-12-31T09:43:28+0000
                        [id] => m_mid.1451555008621:62c3365e35ededc773
                        [to] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => rajesh Prasad Shah
                                                [email] => 543634645764577@facebook.com
                                                [id] => 543634645764577
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [tags] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => inbox
                                            )

                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => read
                                            )

                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => sent
                                            )

                                        [3] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => source:web
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [message] => Very Good
                        [from] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => rajesh Prasad Shah
                                [email] => 543634645764577@facebook.com
                                [id] => 543634645764577
                            )

                        [created_time] => 2015-09-01T09:13:34+0000
                        [id] => m_mid.1445648574720:c2746f8b55fff17369
                        [to] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => rjtest
                                                [email] => 849929567895403@facebook.com
                                                [id] => 849929567895403
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [tags] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => inbox
                                            )

                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => read
                                            )

                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => source:chat
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [message] => Good
                        [from] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => rajesh Prasad Shah
                                [email] => 543634645764577@facebook.com
                                [id] => 543634645764577
                            )

                        [created_time] => 2015-09-01T09:13:32+0000
                        [id] => m_mid.1445648572476:316f06a4adc6d7dd57
                        [to] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => rjtest
                                                [email] => 849929567895403@facebook.com
                                                [id] => 849929567895403
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [tags] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [data] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => inbox
                                            )

                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => read
                                            )

                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [name] => source:chat
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

This is my php code from that i fetch data

```
foreach($data as $evaluatemessage){
   //echo "<pre>";print_r($evaluatemessage); die;
 $inbox=array();
  $inbox['thread_id']=$evaluatemessage['threadId'];
  foreach($evaluatemessage['messages'] as $messagedet){
    //print_r($messagedet[0]['id']); die;
  $inbox['smg_id']=$messagedet[$j]['id'];
  $inbox['body']=$messagedet[$j]['message'];
  $inbox['time']=$messagedet[$j]['created_time'];

  //$inbox['msg_type']=$data;
 //$inbox['user_id']=$data;
  $inbox['From_name']=$messagedet[$j]['from']->name;
   $inbox['To_name']=$messagedet[$j]['to']->data[0]->name;
   $inbox['From_id']=$messagedet[$j]['from']->id;
   $inbox['To_id']=$messagedet[$j]['to']->data[0]->id;


  $inbox['tags']=$messagedet[$j]['tags']->data[1]->name;
 //$inbox['Page_id']=$data;
 //echo "<pre>";print_r($inbox); die;
 $inbox['Page_id']='12345';
   $this->facebook_inboxes->save($inbox);
   $j++;
  }


 $i++;
 }
```

when i hit with this code only a single threadid and single message contents are saved.but rest are not,i want every thread id with there all messages id and message body are saved row by row but unable to do that can anyone help me how i do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this code before Save function

```
$this->facebook_inboxes->create();
```

This is enbuild function of cake to store multiple row.

Answer (score 0):

There is another messages array inside the messages array. So according to your array structure, your second loop will be like this :

```
foreach($evaluatemessage['messages']['messages'] as $messagedet){

  //print_r($messagedet[0]['id']); die;
  $inbox['smg_id']=$messagedet[$j]['id'];
  $inbox['body']=$messagedet[$j]['message'];
  $inbox['time']=$messagedet[$j]['created_time'];

.
.
.

}
```

and you are using only:

```
foreach($evaluatemessage['messages'] as $messagedet){}
```

here is the full code :

```
foreach($data as $evaluatemessage){
   //echo "<pre>";print_r($evaluatemessage); die;
 $inbox=array();
  $inbox['thread_id']=$evaluatemessage['threadId'];
  foreach($evaluatemessage['messages']['messages'] as $messagedet){
    //print_r($messagedet[0]['id']); die;
  $inbox['smg_id']=$messagedet[$j]['id'];
  $inbox['body']=$messagedet[$j]['message'];
  $inbox['time']=$messagedet[$j]['created_time'];

  //$inbox['msg_type']=$data;
 //$inbox['user_id']=$data;
  $inbox['From_name']=$messagedet[$j]['from']->name;
   $inbox['To_name']=$messagedet[$j]['to']->data[0]->name;
   $inbox['From_id']=$messagedet[$j]['from']->id;
   $inbox['To_id']=$messagedet[$j]['to']->data[0]->id;


  $inbox['tags']=$messagedet[$j]['tags']->data[1]->name;
 //$inbox['Page_id']=$data;
 //echo "<pre>";print_r($inbox); die;
 $inbox['Page_id']='12345';
   $this->facebook_inboxes->save($inbox);
   $j++;
  }


 $i++;
 }
```

Comment: hello threadid t_mid.1445648572476:316f06a4adc6d7dd57 data are inserted but threr are another 3 thread id whose data not inserted.

Comment: But there is no other 'threadid t_mid' in the array you given.

Comment: then provide the full array having all the three threadid, i will update my answer